# Unable to click this hyperlink using Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, click, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have a button(hyperlink) with its equivalent HTML code as:

```
<span title="Enroll in Classes" class="SSSBUTTON_CONFIRMLINK">
<a class="SSSBUTTON_CONFIRMLINK" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'DERIVED_REGFRM1_LINK_ADD_ENRL$118$');" tabindex="202" ptlinktgt="pt_peoplecode" id="DERIVED_REGFRM1_LINK_ADD_ENRL$118$" name="DERIVED_REGFRM1_LINK_ADD_ENRL$118$">Proceed to Step 2 of 3</a>
</span>
```

I want to click the button 10 seconds after the page is loaded and I use the following code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Add to cart
// @namespace   Class
// @description Script to add to cart
// @include     http://go.oasis.com/add/?STRM=2141
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

setInterval (clickOnProceedButton, 10 * 1000)

function clickOnProceedButton () {
    var targSubmit  = $("#DERIVED_REGFRM1_LINK_ADD_ENRL$118$");
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    targSubmit[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

The above script is not working and does not click the button. Can someone point out what is wrong here, please?

EDIT:
I get the following error in the Console

```
ERROR: Execution of script 'Add to cart' failed! Object [object global] has no method 'clickOnProceedButton'
TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'clickOnProceedButton'
    at Object.eval (unknown source)), 25:14)
    at Object.eval (unknown source)), 27:4)
    at ag (unknown source), 190:4)
    at K (unknown source), 190:46)
    at o (unknown source), 456:2)
    at U (unknown source), 460:85)
    at R (unknown source), 229:40)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to escape `$` so try `var targSubmit  = $("#DERIVED_REGFRM1_LINK_ADD_ENRL\\$118\\$");`

Comment: @Satpal - Sorry, not working.

Answer (score 1):

Perfectly working in **Google Chrome** but not working in **IE8**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WX48M/)

**HTML:**

```
<a  href="https://google.com"  id="DERIVED_REGFRM1_LINK_ADD_ENRL$118$" >Proceed to Step 2 of 3</a>
```

**JS:**

```
function clickOnProceedButton () {
var targSubmit  =  document.getElementById("DERIVED_REGFRM1_LINK_ADD_ENRL$118$");
var clickEvent  = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
targSubmit.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

}

might help you.

Comment: This is not working, either! Not able to even get the alert window to pop up.

Comment: on which browser you are using..?

Comment: Firefox. But tried it with Chrome too with Tampermonkey extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(clickOnProceedButton, 10 * 1000);
function clickOnProceedButton() {
    var link = document.getElementById("DERIVED_REGFRM1_LINK_ADD_ENRL$118$");
    if(link) {
        link.click();
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P4Hvp/)

Comment: It seems document.getElementById() is not retrieving anything. So clicking action is not happening. Your demo works fine.